# Running count of rows that have a sum less than a user defined amount

Tags: mysql, vba, excel

I have an excel spreadsheet that uses a numbered scale to estimate a level of effort associated with that particular task. I need to be able to calculate a running sum of those items until I go beyond that number, and not include the one that goes beyond in the count. I then need to total up the number of rows included in the sum until that point. I then need to identify that last item, probably by highlighting that row, then start the operation again for the remaining items below. This should continue until I have gone through all items in the spreadsheet.

I know the question is sort of confusing. The level of effort is used as a calculation to determine the amount of work that can be completed in a production cycle. that total number is used to estimate how many items can be completed in the upcoming production cycles, hence user defined amount as this number will change each cycle. The reason I need to be able to identify how many items are included and highlight the row is so we can determine "Milestones" so we can tell our customer, next milestone we can get you all the following items.

I honestly have no idea where to even start with this issue, I know I will need to complete this task in VBA most likely which is fine I am very comfortable with VBA. I am supposing I need to use it like an on demand function through a button click or something that will first generate a database of the items that exist then run SQL queries to get me where i need to be. Any help anyone can provide would be vastly appreciated and thanks in advance to anyone that has ideas.

Comment: Start by enumerating the steps. Then chip away at each of those steps one by one.  Try to google for each.  I think each step is its own question possibly... after you try to accomplish it yourself.  But I think you're misunderstanding a few things if you think you'll be doing SQL queries in VBA, unless there's database involved that you didn't mention.

Comment: No no database involved here. I think I may have found a way to do this with an excel formula actually that would calculate a running total until a specified criteria then would reset. If I can get that to work I can function out the remaining steps by just using a countif or something.

Comment: Your question would be much improved with the inclusion of sample data and expected results. As it stands seems pretty simple for a script to loop through a range and aggregating the relevant values. Then on each loop you can check if the total value exceeds your user defined amount. If it does you can output your results on the right line and reset your counters. Hope this points you in the right direction.

Comment: https://goo.gl/eDI1tH

All this work is manually done in the example. Column A has the current velocity total, Column B is irrelevant for this, Column C has the estimated totals, Column D is hidden but just counts whether B is a number or not, Column E displays a count total where the included items get as close to the velocity without going over and Column F is that total.